# why break point not work when using CE(cheat engine) to debug a game in Android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, cheat-engine

By CE, I have searched a game value in the process of Android emulator (Although the game runs in Android system not PC, data of the game is stored in emulator process. So I directly use CE to search that value in emulator process). But a break point of that value doesn't work.

Why? I think Android game running in PC must be translated into assembler by Android emulator, because PC only understand machine code. Then we can set a break point to find out which code change that value.